# c# Possibilities after userinput (textbox)

Tags: c#, list, user-input

I'm not sure how to ask this so I will use an example:

**Words:** Soccer, Swimming, Swordfighting Tennis, Baseball, Basketball, Formule1, Fishing, Cycling, ...

**Control:** txtSports

When the user inputs the letter "s" in the TextBox i would like to get the possibilities that starts with an "s". (Soccer, Swimming, Swordfighting) If the user then inputs "w" (Swimming, Swordfighting) and so on.

How can I do this? I'm doing this in c# (Windows 8 Application)

Comment: You're looking for "autocomplete".

Comment: even it's German, I'm sure you will understand the following: http://dotnet-snippets.de/snippet/autocomplete-textbox/634

Answer (score 2):

You should use the autocomplete feature of the text box. [Here's a nice article about it](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/mahesh/AutoCompletion02012006113508AM/AutoCompletion.aspx).

Comment: Just noticed that the autocomplete feature doesn't work in Windows 8 Applications.

Comment: Is there any alternative for metro apps?

Comment: Sorry, currently I have no experience with Windows RT applications, so [I suggest you use Google](http://www.google.com/search?btnG=1&pws=0&q=autocomplete+textbox+winrt). Good luck ;)